# Error with Vue.js 3, Pinia and global store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I have the following problem when using Pinia in a Vue.js 3 project. I am loading some constant JSON structures from my backend, with the following `src/store/constants.store.ts`

```
// @ts-check
import { defineStore } from "pinia"
import ConstantsApi from "@/api/constants"

export const useConstantsStore = defineStore("constants", {
    state: () => ({
        instanceTiers: [],
        instanceStatuses: [],
        queueStatuses: [],
        countries: [],
        areConstantsLoaded: false,
    }),
    actions: {
        async fetchConstants() {
            this.instanceTiers = await ConstantsApi.instanceTiers();
            this.instanceStatuses = await ConstantsApi.instanceStatuses();
            this.queueStatuses = await ConstantsApi.queueStatuses();
            this.countries = await ConstantsApi.countries();
            this.areConstantsLoaded = true;
        },
    },
})
```

That is using the following `src/api/constants.ts`

```
import {api} from "./api"

export default {
    instanceTiers() {
        return api("GET", "/instance_tiers");
    },
    instanceStatuses() {
        return api("GET", "/instance_statuses");
    },
    queueStatuses() {
        return api("GET", "/queue_statuses");
    },
    countries() {
        return api("GET", "/countries");
    }
}
```

As you can see, the general method used to fetch information from the backend is contained in `src/api/api.ts`, as follows

```
import {APISettings} from './config';
import {useAuthStore} from "@/stores";
import {useNotificationStore} from '@/stores';

const authStore = useAuthStore();

const notificationStore = useNotificationStore();

export function api(method: string, url: string): Promise<any>;
export function api(method: string, url: string, data: any): Promise<any>;
export function api(method: string, url: string, data?: any): Promise<any> {
    return fetch(APISettings.baseURL + url, {
        method,
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: APISettings.headers,
        body: data != null ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 401) {
            authStore.logout();
            return;
        }
        if (response.status == 403) {
            response.json().then((data) => {
                notificationStore.notifications.push({
                    type: 'error',
                    description: "403 forbidden",
                    timeout: 5000,
                });
            });
            return;
        }
        if (response.status == 404) {
            response.json().then((data) => {
                notificationStore.notifications.push({
                    type: 'error',
                    description: "404 not found",
                    timeout: 5000,
                });
            });
            return;
        }
        if (response.status == 409) {
            response.json().then((data) => {
                notificationStore.notifications.push({
                    type: 'error',
                    description: data.detail,
                    timeout: 5000,
                });
            });
            return false;
        }
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            response.json().then((data) => {
                notificationStore.notifications.push({
                    type: 'error',
                    description: "500 Internal error",
                    timeout: 5000,
                });
            });
            return;
        }
        if (response.status > 201) {
            return;
        }
        return response.json();
    }).catch(function (error) {
        notificationStore.notifications.push({
            type: 'error',
            description: data,
            timeout: 5000,
        });
    });
}
```

All the API requests are subjected to authorization; I store the auth credentials within `src/store/auth.store.ts`, as follows:

```
// @ts-check
import { defineStore } from "pinia"

export const useAuthStore = defineStore("auth", {
  state: () => ({
    token: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")) as string,
    idToken: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("idToken-parsed")),
    logoutUrl: localStorage.getItem("logout-url") as string,
    loginUrl: localStorage.getItem("login-url") as string,
  }),
  getters: {
    getToken: (state) => {
      return state.token
    },
    getIdToken: (state) => {
      return state.idToken
    },
    getLogoutUrl: (state) => {
      return state.logoutUrl
    }
   },
  actions: {
    logout() {
      localStorage.removeItem("token")
      localStorage.removeItem("idToken-parsed")
      localStorage.removeItem("logout-url")
      localStorage.removeItem("refresh-token")
      window.location.href = this.logoutUrl;
    },
  },
})
```

Moreover, I have a `src/stores/index.ts` file in my project as well, where I use the `createPinia()` method

```
export * from "./auth.store";
export * from "./notification.store";
export * from "./dynamic_sidebar.store";
export * from "./constants.store";

import { createPinia } from "pinia";

export const pinia = createPinia();
```

When loading a page, why do I have the following error?

> Uncaught Error: []: getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?

I have my `src/main.ts` like this

```
import { createApp } from "vue"
import { pinia } from "./stores"
import App from "./App.vue"
import { router } from "./router"
import "./assets/main.css"

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(pinia);
app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");
```

Everything works if I change my `src/stores/constants.store.ts` to:

```
// @ts-check
import { defineStore } from "pinia"

export const useConstantsStore = defineStore("constants", {
    state: () => ({
        instanceTiers: [],
        instanceStatuses: [],
        queueStatuses: [],
        countries: [],
        areConstantsLoaded: false,
    }),
    actions: {
        async fetchConstants() {
            this.instanceTiers = [];
            this.instanceStatuses = [];
            this.queueStatuses = [];
            this.countries = [];
            this.areConstantsLoaded = true;
        },
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to create Pinia's instance with the `createPinia` function.

So, your code should be like the following example:

```
import { createApp } from "vue"
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import App from "./App.vue"
import { router } from "./router"
import "./assets/main.css"

const app = createApp(App);
const pinia = createPinia();
app.use(pinia);
app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");
```

Comment: I'd assume that `const pinia = createPinia()` happens inside "./stores", but this needs to be confirmed

Comment: @raphael-marques  Sorry, I forgot to include another file. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

`useAuthStore` isn't supposed to be called at the top of a module, this defies the purpose of having getter function for a store. When used outside a component, `useAuthStore` should be always called at the place where a store is used in order to prevent early store instantiation, i.e. inside `api`:

```
import {APISettings} from './config';
import {useAuthStore, useNotificationStore} from '@/stores';

export function api(method: string, url: string): Promise<any>;
export function api(method: string, url: string, data: any): Promise<any>;
export function api(method: string, url: string, data?: any): Promise<any> {
export function api(method: string, url: string, data?: any): Promise<any> {
  const authStore = useAuthStore();
  const notificationStore = useNotificationStore();
  ...
```

Also `src/api/constants.ts` seems to be a useless abstraction, this code belongs to store actions.

It's possible that `src/main.ts` doesn't look exactly like it's shown, but in case it is, this means that Pinia isn't correctly initialized and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77037393/3731501) is also applicable.

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand how you are suggesting to change my code. Could you add more clues?

Comment: I added the changed part, remove use...Store lines above `export function api ...` and place it inside api function

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggestion from @estus-flask does not work

Comment: What does not work? Is the error the same? This may mean that the same problem still occurs somewhere else.

Comment: I still have the same error, but everything works if I change my `src/stores/constants.store.ts` as described at the end of my question.

Comment: I see. Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. A possible explanation is that the change wasn't properly applied for some reason (caching or else), or a similar problem in related code that you didn't show, e.g. useNotificationStore. The cause of the problem in the original code is exactly what the error says, pinia instance was accessed through useAuthStore() call before it was initialized with app.use(pinia). This won't happen with the listed changes

Comment: All the code I have is within the question

Comment: There are no `export * from "./notification.store"; export * from "./dynamic_sidebar.store";` modules at least. Again, the problem has a known cause and a solution, that you cannot solve it with the proposed solutions requires some assistance from your side. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's required by SO rules. At this point the problem cannot be reproduced by anybody but you.